# What causes this Genshi's Template Syntax Error?

Tags: python, syntax-error, genshi

A Genshi template raises the following error:

> TemplateSyntaxError: invalid syntax in expression `"${item.error}"` of `"choose"` directive

The part of the template code that the error specifies is the following (*'feed' is a list of dictionary which is passed to the template*):

```
<item py:for="item in feed">
<py:choose error="${item.error}">
    <py:when error="0">
        <title>${item.something}</title>
    </py:when>
    <py:otherwise>
        <title>${item.something}</title>
    </py:otherwise>
</py:choose>
</item>
```

Basically, item.error holds either a `'0'` or a `'1'` and I want the output based on that. I am not sure where the error is - any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The [docs](http://genshi.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/0.5.x/xml-templates.html#id2) perhaps don't make this clear, but the attribute needs to be called `test` (as it is in their examples) instead of `error`.

```
<item py:for="item in feed">
<py:choose test="item.error">
    <py:when test="0">
        <title>${item.something}</title>
    </py:when>
    <py:otherwise>
        <title>${item.something}</title>
    </py:otherwise>
</py:choose>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Genshi, but based on the documentation I found, it looks like you're trying to use the inline Python expression syntax inside a templates directives argument, which seems to be unneccesary. Try this instead:

```
<item py:for="item in feed">
<py:choose error="item.error">
    <py:when error="0">
        <title>${item.something}</title>
    </py:when>
    <py:otherwise>
        <title>${item.something}</title>
    </py:otherwise>
</py:choose>
</item>
```

Comment: Thanks, Jorenko. I realized the mistake myself and changed it. But it still didn't work. I decided to use two if's instead and that worked.